# Why doesn't $validators update $errors value on ngMessages?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-messages

The validator is being called, and returning true/false as expected.  However, even when the validator returns false, the html still shows the class "ng-valid" instead of "ng-invalid" as expected, for ng-messages to behave properly.  When I use the standard "required" error, there are no problems, but anything custom is not working.

Upon debugging, I've also found that $error is updating with required, but not daysofmonth.

I've created a component that has a custom validator, daysofmonth, that looks like the following:

```
    this.ngModel.$validators.daysofmonth = function(modelValue) {
        modelValue = modelValue || '';
        let pieces = modelValue.split(',');
        let isValid = true;

        pieces.forEach(function(piece) {
            let numberValue = parseInt(piece, 10);

            if (isNaN(numberValue)) {
                if (piece.trim() && piece.trim() !== 'L') {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            } else if (numberValue < 1 || numberValue > 31) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

        return isValid;
    };
```

The html looks like:

```
<form name="form">
    <div>
        <input name="daysofmonth" ng-model="ctrl.daysOfMonth">
    </div>

    <ng-messages for="form.daysofmonth.$error">
        <ng-message when="daysofmonth">Please enter valid days.</ng-message>
    </ng-messages>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

isValid is always true ...

The forEach method is an asynchronous one, so if you want your isValid variable to be up to date at the moment you return it, you have to do so in the callback. But, you would return the result from the callback instead of from your function so, another way, would be to replace your forEach loop by a standard synchronous for loop.